# ORA-06550: line 0, column 0: PLS-00907: cannot load library unit `COLUMN_NAME` (referenced by)

Tags: oracle, ssis, etl

So, I got this error message

> Started:  9:00:01 AM  Error: 2018-01-26 09:33:53.01     Code: 0xC002F210     Source: Run proc SP_MISSING_FILE_CASE_CLOSURE Execute SQL Task     Description: Executing the query "begin  SP_MISSING_FILE_CASE_CLOSURE;  end;" failed with the following error: "ORA-06550: line 0, column 0:  PLS-00907: cannot load library unit USAGE.SP_MISSING_FILE_CASE_CLOSURE (referenced by )". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  9:00:01 AM  Finished: 9:33:53 AM  Elapsed:  2031.88 seconds.  Process Exit Code 1.  The step failed.

sometimes, but sometimes my SSIS job runs normally. Can someone provide me with some kind of solution? I cannot see any pattern in it's failure except `PROCEDURE` which is always the same.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: add more details and package screenshot

Comment: What kind of details I should give you? Also, I cannot give you package screenshot here, sorry. @Mr.Bhosale

Comment: From [Oracle Error messages](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ERRMG/PLS-00049.htm#ERRMG-GUID-C2E95CDD-E8D5-4A63-90C2-41B66DD76B27): _PLS-00907: cannot load library unit string (referenced by string)
Cause: PL/SQL is unable to find and load a library unit that was previously available. **This typically happens when you try to load a unit which references another library unit that is non-existent or invalid.**_ (I'm not sure how `SCHEMA.COLUMN_NAME` is a library unit though.)

Comment: ok. What is flow data and which component you are using? + source + destination ?

Comment: This is thrown by an Execute SQL Task, you have to provide the SQL Statement that this Task try to run

Comment: Execute SQL Task for CASE_CLOSURE one day it passes but other day it doesn't. I don't know why is this happening. The procedure script is fine, I think. I can't find any error in the script. @Mr.Bhosale

Comment: @VladimirTodorov what is the SQL statment of the stored procedure?

Comment: begin
SP_MISSING_FILE_CASE_CLOSURE;
end;
@Hadi

Comment: Try changing the `IsStoredProcedure` property

Comment: @Hadi I have only `IsQueryStoredProcedure` property and it is set to `false`.

Comment: Ok, I found it in properties. If I change it to `true` what should I expect to happen?

Comment: Try changing the sql statement to `SP_MISSING_FILE_CASE_CLOSURE()` and change this property to `True`

Comment: @Hadi Can you please tell me what will this change? I am new in the company and I can not change things just like that :)

Comment: I am not sure if this will solves the issue, but this property is set to True when you only pass a stored procedure name, instead of writing the full query `BEGIN .... END;`

Comment: @Hadi It ended with error

>ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Comment: Ok forget about it. In the initial sql statement try the following  logic `Execute Schema.Procedure`

Comment: try `begin execute <schema>.SP_MISSING_FILE_CASE_CLOSURE; end;`

Comment: @Hadi , Okay, I will, but what should I do with `IsStoredProcedure`?

Comment: Leave it equal `False`

Comment: @Hadi Thank you so much. Type it as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this syntax (add schema)

```
begin 
execute  <schema>.SP_MISSING_FILE_CASE_CLOSURE; 
end;
```